# What is OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

What is a brief explanation of the OpenAPI?
I read the documentation, and watched some tutorials, but didn't get the idea

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically a documentation of APIs. We can add the url, response, body, params etc for all methods like GET, POST, PUT, DELETE etc and for all the responses 200, 500 etc.

Refer https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/